# Searching the proper format in php unpack function

Tags: php, format, unpack

The output is the result of the codes:

```
    $bytes= fread($handle,"32");
    print_r(unpack("La/fb/fc/fd/fe/ff/fg/fh",$bytes)); 


Array ( [a] => 20150416 [b] => 1.0499999523163 [c] => 1.25 [d] => 1.0299999713898 
[e] => 1.1900000572205 [f] => 509427008 [g] => 566125248 [h] => 509427008 )
```

How to write the proper format in unpack if the wanted output is as following  ?

```
Array ( [1] => 20150416 [2] => 1.0499999523163 [3] => 1.25 [4] => 1.0299999713898 
[5] => 1.1900000572205 [6] => 509427008 [7] => 566125248 [8] => 509427008 )
```

Comment: i think you are looking for `array_values()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Or, just replace change unpack string to `L1/f2/f3/f4/f5/f6/f7/f8`

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: the string L1/f2/f3/f4/f5/f6/f7/f8  is wrong format ,i have tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/array_values), it keeps the order (first index is 0):

```
$bytes = fread($handle,"32");
$un = unpack("La/fb/fc/fd/fe/ff/fg/fh",$bytes);
print_r(array_values($un));
```

Edit (if you want first index 1):

```
$bytes = fread($handle,"32");
$un = unpack("La/fb/fc/fd/fe/ff/fg/fh",$bytes);
array_unshift($un, NULL);
$array = array_values($un);
unset($array[0]);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: That would be base 0 not base 1